# Ubuntu 21.04 and Conky/ Conky Manager widgets doesn't show up! Please, help

Tags: themes, conky, widgets, 21.04

after testing different Linux distros, I fit my self with Ubuntu for the major compatibility softwares with my machine. Now, one of the problem that I'm facing it's with Conky and Conky Manager, where on the latest Debian/Deepin distribution I did not have this problem.

After hours spend to understand why Conky Manager 2.4 **wont** install in Ubuntu 21.04 (in Debian/ Deepin can be installed without troubles) because caused for some lib broken not compatible with the latest Ubuntu, to whom it needs just yesterday I discovered that can be solved it with the installation of the package lib `realpath_8.26-3ubuntu4_all.deb` or simply install the latest fork Conky Manager 2.
Now strict to my problem point, second obstacle that I'm face it's, when I try to activate any widgets from the basic to my new widgets, Conky Manager it doesn't show anything (by terminal the basic black theme conky it works/ show up) ; where on the latest Debian/ Deepin - even if not perfect - but can show properly all the widgets "out of the box". I'm missing some other libs on Ubuntu to let it work properly? Or the problem it's in another area?

Please, I hope someone can help me on that.
Cris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 2 (Fixed):**

I have fixed and found all the solutions on that, to let Conky to work properly on new **Ubuntu 21.04**, and it needs as following:

**1.** To install Conky or Conky-All, even if can be installed by Terminal or by Synaptics Packages Manager (if doesn't give you any error) in the second step you will not be able to apply any new Widget downloaded and apply by Conky Manager, can show only the basic black Conky as the test to see if it's working, but in fact you cannot apply any new widget because will not show in the end.
**Solution**: go here `https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/wiki/Installation`  install the libs needs for the self building installation `apt-get install cmake libimlib2-dev libncurses5-dev libx11-dev libxdamage-dev libxft-dev libxinerama-dev libxml2-dev libxext-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev liblua5.3-dev` and follow the instraction till the `make install` command (if you need more futures like Conky-All for sure you have to install other dev libraries by your self, just follow where missing libs are required during the installation). This will allows us to install Conky properly with all the futures well working without bugs.

**2.** To install Conky Manager 2.4 the original from  teejee2008, you can find in GitHub section here: `https://github.com/teejee2008/conky-manager/releases` you must in the latest Ubuntu Os to install the following package `realpath_8.26-3ubuntu4_all.deb` (or later future versions). Or if you don't want install the abandoned original Conky Manager you can install the following fork `Conky-Manager2` now in `2.7-2 version` , search on google you will find easily. And then your widgets will work and appear properly.

**3.** As in my case, in case your widgets will work but will not show any Bar Graph related to your CPU/GPU/RAM or wherever hardware that your widgets will monitoring even if you have installed all the related packaging sensors like `psensor` or `lm-sensors` or wherever you need for your widgets, the problem it's located into the Lua file settings from your widgets projects; go to find the command line `loadstring` and change int `load`. This because, the `loadstring` function since `Lua 5.2`, has been replaced by `load` that it's vital to let work properly the Graphical Bars (CPU /GPU and so on) under the voice `lua gradbar` coding into the file widget settings.

Preface, all these problems I didn't have got in Debian because working everything "out of the box", so any Distro can react in different ways, the above solutions are for Ubuntu 21.04.
Hope can be usefully for others because I spent some days to solve all these obstacles.....

Comment: Thank you for this elaborated information. I am able to install Conky Manager. However, when I try to apply the configuration, it is not getting applied. I can't see anything on my desktop.

Comment: Hello @Rivindra Gullapalli, I know and from my tests, Conky can be installed in different ways;  but - as also you said - will not work any widget, the unique way to let them works it will be to delete any trace of previous Conky and Conky-Manager restart, and once you are sure that everything it's deleted well. You MUST to build up Conky into your system by following this page " https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/wiki/Installation " , then install " realpath_8.26-3ubuntu4_all.deb " and then install the original Conky from here " https://teejeetech.com/conky-manager/ " .......

Comment: Edit 2: Please, keep in mind that are missing many libs in Ubuntu, when you will building and I suggest  to use the " cmake .. " Option to build with the BUILD_FLAGS to install Conky with full and unlocked futures in CCMAKE build GIU you will get many errors because are missing the related libs that you need for different functions and sometimes even if you will install the missing libs and persist the error that tells you " you are missing the related lib " this it's a small bug...

Comment: if that;  you need simply to re-download the Github Conky sourch folder and restart the building process and then will not give you the same error...